# Windows Identity Foundation and OID

Tags: wif, oid

I am new to WIF (Windows Identity Foundation). I've been reading about it but i have some doubts.

Is it possible to use WIF to authenticate against directory services other than AD (for example, OID) and for authentication can I connect to databases (SQL and Oracle)?

Answer (score 2):

WIF doesn't actually do the authentication - it's a set of .NET classes which handle the WS-Federation protocol and token management e.g. signing, encrypting.

The authentication is provided by the STS that WIF "binds" to.

In the classic model, WIF binds to ADFS which can only authenticate against AD.

However, by using another STS (e.g. [IdentityServer](http://thinktecture.github.io/)) you can authenticate against SQL Server.

You can roll your own STS which can authenticate against anything you want.